# A class that inherits from str and Enum, how can I use in Python3.8

Tags: string, enums, format, python-3.8

I have a class like this:

```
from enum import Enum
import json

class Status(str, Enum):
    START = 'start'
    END = 'end'

data = {
    'status': Status.START
}

# This is not what I want
print('\nbad:\n')
print(data)
print(Status.START)
print('%s' % Status.START)
print(str(Status.START))

# This is what I want
print('\ngood:\n')
print(json.dumps(data))
print(f'{Status.START}')
print(format(Status.START))
with open('tmp_file', 'w') as f:
    f.write(Status.START)
with open('tmp_file', 'r') as f:
    print('The content of file:')
    print(f.read())
```

The output are:

[image]

I want to always get the string 'start' through 'Status.START', but as shown above, sometimes I need to convert. Can you explain to me the reason of this problem? How do I use it?

Comment: When I write using python redis client, like `redis.hset(key, mapping=data)`, the value is also `start` in redis, but when I `str(Status.START)`, I got `Status.START`. The difference in the above output bothers me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `enum.StrEnum` instead to allow the `__str__` method of the `str` type to take over:

```
from enum import StrEnum

class Status(StrEnum):
    START = 'start'
    END = 'end'
```

Comment: `StrEnum` doesn't exist in 3.8.